# .NET creating corrupt files

Tags: .net, file, stream

I am trying to create images using .NET. Below is the code that I am using. This works fine most of the time but sometimes I guess that the stream gets cut off and I have a corrupt file. I am getting the image via its URL.

I am really looking for someone to correct my code or provide me insight as to what else I can do.

Thanks

```
// Function will return the number of bytes processed
        // to the caller. Initialize to 0 here.
        int bytesProcessed = 0;

        // Assign values to these objects here so that they can
        // be referenced in the finally block
        Stream remoteStream = null;
        Stream localStream = null;
        WebResponse response = null;

        // Use a try/catch/finally block as both the WebRequest and Stream
        // classes throw exceptions upon error
        try
        {
            // Create a request for the specified remote file name
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(remoteFilename);
            if (request != null)
            {
                // Send the request to the server and retrieve the
                // WebResponse object 
                response = request.GetResponse();
                if (response != null)
                {
                    // Once the WebResponse object has been retrieved,
                    // get the stream object associated with the response's data
                    remoteStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                    // Create the local file
                    localStream = File.Create(localFilename);

                    // Allocate a 1k buffer
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead;

                    // Simple do/while loop to read from stream until
                    // no bytes are returned
                    do
                    {
                        // Read data (up to 1k) from the stream
                        bytesRead = remoteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        // Write the data to the local file
                        localStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                        // Increment total bytes processed
                        bytesProcessed += bytesRead;
                    } while (bytesRead > 0);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close the response and streams objects here 
            // to make sure they're closed even if an exception
            // is thrown at some point
            if (response != null) response.Close();
            if (remoteStream != null) remoteStream.Close();
            if (localStream != null) localStream.Close();
        }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Main Exception
MESSAGE: Parameter is not valid.
SOURCE: System.Drawing
TARGETSITE: System.Drawing.Image FromStream(System.IO.Stream, Boolean, Boolean)
STACKTRACE: at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
            at Sitecore.Resources.Media.ImageMedia.GetImage() at Sitecore.Resources.Media.ImageMedia.UpdateMetaData(MediaStream mediaStream)
            at Sitecore.Resources.Media.JpegMedia.UpdateMetaData(MediaStream mediaStream) at Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator.AttachStreamToMediaItem(Stream stream, String itemPath, String fileName, MediaCreatorOptions options)
            at Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator.CreateFromStream(Stream stream, String filePath, MediaCreatorOptions options)
            at Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator.CreateFromFile(String filePath, MediaCreatorOptions options)
```

Comment: Are any exceptions caught?? And what do they say??

Comment: Why are you catching an exception only to throw it again, but losing the stack trace? And why aren't you using `using` statements?

Comment: Sometimes an interrupted TCP connection doesn't give any error but just behaves like the end of the stream was reached. When I wrote a downloader in C#, I downloaded to a temporary file, and only moved it to the target filename once I verified that the expected size(from the http header) matches the downloaded size.

Comment: What are the odds that the image file actually contains a http 404 error message?  Or anything really.  Take a look at it with a hex viewer.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Sometimes such as how? The only way you can get an end of stream from a TCP connection inside the peer sends a FIN, which by definition is a completed connection, not an interrupted one.

Comment: @EJP I don't know what caused it, but definitely ended up with incomplete http downloads and no error indication other than the http length header not matching the file size. I cared about getting a reliable downloader, not about trouble shooting the root cause. Perhaps the website's load balancer/reverse proxy send a mistaken FIN, perhaps it was a bug in the http client library. (And that was without SOCKS proxy, Tor Browser marks incomplete downloads as completed all the time, because apparently the proxy loses the distinction between loss of connectivity and properly terminated connections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the file being locked by Windows. Basically, there were two servers. Saved the file on another server where it should have been and it all worked.