# "Interrupted" TCP connections

Tags: http, networking, tcp, connection, reliability

I am looking at this question: [.NET creating corrupt files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195801/net-creating-corrupt-files), specifically @CodesInChaos's comment:

> Sometimes an interrupted TCP connection doesn't give any error but
>   just behaves like the end of the stream was reached

I searched more about this and got here: [The Mysteries of Connection Close](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/http-the-definitive/1565925092/ch04s07.html)

> Any HTTP client, server, or proxy can close a TCP transport connection
>   at any time. The connections normally are closed  at the end of a
>   message,[18] but during error conditions, the connection may be closed
>   in the middle of a header line or in other **strange places**
>   ...
>   When a client or proxy receives an HTTP response terminating in
>   connection close, and the **actual transferred entity length  doesn't**
>   **match the Content-Length** (or there is no Content-Length), the receiver
>   should question the correctness of the length.

**Q:** How is it possible that a transport layer error can silently propagate up without raising an exception? I thought TCP standard includes error handling - checksums, packet sequence numbers and so on. Does anyone have any more information, for example what can be causing such errors, or steps to troubleshoot?

---

Edit: [example 1](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/3047)

> some of the responses contains JSON that is truncated. i.e. we get a status of 200 however the JSON is malformed and truncated
>   ...
>   Also sent the details to MS support with the source code and they can reproduce on their side as well

[example 2](https://serverfault.com/questions/612807/why-is-this-http-request-being-truncated)

> We've got a user who is getting an error on a page due to an HTTP request getting truncated.

Comment: The comment there by @CodesInChaos is not correct. Nothing terminates a TCP connection cleanly except a close or send dshutdown by the peer. If you're using HTTP you should check that the content-length is correct, and if you're using a decent HTTP library it should do that for you.

Comment: I've seen reports of this behaviour though, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918455/httpwebresponse-returns-an-incomplete-stream, https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8892/httpwebreponse-incomplete-sometimes

Comment: So if this did happen, would it be always caused by the HTTP library implementation?